# Spring-Data-Neo4J: How do log into the remote server?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using Spring-Data-Neo4j 4.0.0.M1, and trying to connect to the server. I'm getting an exception:

`Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized`

I have a password on the server interface, but I'm not sure how to tell Spring about it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.noxgroup.nitro.persistence")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer () {
        /*** I was quite surprised not to see an overloaded parameter here ***/ 
        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("org.my.software.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
                if (event.getEntity() instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User) event.getEntity();
                    user.encodePassword();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Side Note**

*4.0.0 Milestone 1 is absolutely fantastic. If anyone is using 3.x.x, I'd recommend checking it out!*

Comment: Re: the side node, good to hear that! Please use snapshot builds as a lot has been added or fixed since the M1 release. RC1 expected very soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The username and password are passed currently via system properties

e.g.

```
-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dusername=<usr> -Dpassword=<pwd>"
```

or

```
 System.setProperty("username", "neo4j");
 System.setProperty("password", "password");
```

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-627 is open (not targeted for 4.0 RC1 though), please feel free to add comments/vote it up

Comment: This isn't working for me :( I'm still getting "unauthorised". I'm using the same username and password that I use to log into the browser interface for neo4j.

Comment: That's strange. I just re-verified this using the example app https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university with mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dusername=<usr> -Dpassword=<pwd>"
Also verified it with another application where I do a System.setProperty in the constructor of the Neo4jConfiguration implementation. Do you have some code I can look at?

Comment: Sorry, I was setting the properties *after* calling RemoteServer(...). My bad :)